# I have a time series dataset. I am looking to answer 2 forecast questions:

Tags: regression, time-series, arima

(1) At any given time 't' the machine is upstate/downstate (logistic)

(2) Forecasting total downtime of the machine in the coming 10 weeks?

The dataset looks like this where Count is no of downtimes occurred in the day and Length is the total length of downtime (in mins) for the day

Day | Count | Length

1      3       25

2      0        0

3      1       50

How should I go answering it. I used the auto.arima function from forecast package but the forecasting is a straight line. Anyidea how can I improve in answering the above questions?

Comment: Machinery often has working parts replaced for maintenance before they break, because as the total in-service runtime of a part increases it is more likely to fail. If all of the parts in a given machine are soon due for maintenance replacement, failure is more likely than if all of the same parts were recently replaced. As a practical matter the data that you have is, by itself, not likely to give a sufficiently accurate answer for industrial or military use. An important statistic for such parts is "Mean Time Between Failures", or MTBF and you do not appear to have this type of data.

Comment: @JamesPhillips: Thank you for pointing that out. I made some adjustments to the data to calculate MTBF from the data. However, I am still facing the issue of flat forecasts when running auto.arima and forecast functions. I also see that my data has few days off where the plant was shutdown completely. How do I tackle such variations in my data.

Comment: During shutdowns, no wear or material fatigue such as "work hardening" to initiate crack propagation should occur, so you could subtract that number of days from the regression input data. Perhaps you could lengthen the future forecast days by the known number of shutdown days scheduled on the calendar.